# HTML "required" attribute for multiple button with multiple text field on same form

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I have HTML form which has multiple button and multiple text fields on same form some thing like below.

**Form: #myform**

```
TextField1 ---> Button1
TextField2 ---> Button2
.. so on like more number of fields
```

I want to apply "required" attribute only specific button to specific textfield (Button1 for TextField1 )

It will be grateful if someone provide solution in javascript by passing some parameter to perform this validation

Comment: Try to use this please (is javascript):

**`document.getElementById('TextField1').setAttribute("required", "Button1");
document.getElementById('TextField2').setAttribute("required", "Button2");`**

Comment: @JCHernández Thanks for your quick soln there is small conflicts in this soln , When I have entered value in TextField1 and hit Button1 works fine and when I clear  TextField1 and hit Button2 it is considering TextField1  is "required" since it was already called , do you have any other optimal soln on this. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to suit my requirement which I asked in automated fashion, I am posting the code so that might be useful if someone searching solution like me

**Calling function on button click**

```
    <input type="text" id="txtfield1" class="texttype0" th:field="*{txtfield1}" placeholder="Enter txtfield1"> 
    <button type="submit" id="bt1" onclick="btn('txtfield1')" name="action" >Update</button>
```

**And below is my javascript function**

```
function btn(txtid) {
        document.getElementById(txtid).setAttribute("required", true);
    $('form#myform').find(
                'input[type=text],input[type=date],select').each(
                function() {
                    var name = $(this).attr('id');
                    if (txtid == name) {
                        $(name).prop("required", true);
                    } else {
                        $(name).prop("required", false);
                        document.getElementById(name).required = false;
                    }
                });
    }
```

This will search all element from a form and remove require attribute except the one which you passed in parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes) "required" is not included. So "required" is not allowed on element "button". You can add, but it will not add validation. For button and  i would use validation with javascript.

Comment: You have any sample code or solution to handle this scenario in javascript ?

Comment: You can add a hidden (but hidden with CSS {display: none;}, because "required" not work with type="hidden" ) input with attribute "required" and switch the value from "" to "1" (or something else) when you click the appropriate button. For a good customer experience have to change color or text of button to show is clicked or not.

Comment: I am not worried about mozilla for now I just need soln based on "required" attribute